# Why inline function doesn't catch a variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want a callback to be called when a user clicks on a marker. I've figured out that if I use an inline defined function, the variable I want to use has a value corresponding to the last used value. In a code below it's a last value of `data` array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var data = [
  {Name: 'Limanowskiego 1', Lat: 53.785418, Long: 20.4907734},
  {Name: 'Partyzantów 12', Lat: 53.782255, Long: 20.484778}];

function createCallback(p) {
  return function(e) {
    console.log(p);
  };
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.785418, 20.4907734)
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "test string"
  });

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var point = data[i];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: point.Name,
      });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      console.log(point);
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I replace the listener registration by:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', createCallback(point));
```

it works as expected.

Comment: You have function(e) in your first code block, but console.log(point) in that function. How does the function know what point is?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you aren't telling the anonymous function here what point is.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      console.log(point); //point?? what point?
    });
```

You could probably solve this by simply adjusting your parameters accordingly...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e, point) { //Oh, This point!
      console.log(point);
    });
```

If you don't understand why this is, it's because `point` was declared in the surrounding function as a local variable, not a global variable (which is best!).

When you create the new, anonymous function, it creates its own scope, and it doesn't know anything about the other function's `point`. To tell the anonymous function which point to use, you can just pass it in as a parameter, hence my answer above.